# What do you have to do to get the Site association bonus?

Tags: support, association

What classifies as being associated with a site? I visit many different sites and have yet to see a bonus. Or do you have to post to get the bonus?

Comment: TL;DR: Amount of sites isn't a factor. You need 200 rep on one, and you get bonus of 100 on all of them.